# Do Gdiplus::Bitmap::Lock/UnlockBits always copy data?

Tags: c++, windows, gdi+

Do Gdiplus::Bitmap::Lock/UnlockBits always copy the data? Or are there situations when it can map the relevant pages to the address space of my process, giving me a zero-copy direct access?

If yes, what are the known restrictions on the parameters (like a specific format, maybe only when the whole image is requested, etc...)?

If no, then why not? The interface looks like it was intended to provide a direct access when possible. Is it just Microsoft's laziness, or there is some technical obstacle?

Comment: The abstraction level of LockBits is very, very high.  How much work needs to be done completely depends on the image codec, the pixel format you ask for, whether the image was loaded from a stream or a file and whether your program has accessed the pixel data before.  "Laziness" is certainly an unproductive way to think about it.

Comment: @Hans: so your comment implies that it always copies? I'm interested only in bitmaps created with the (width, height, format) constructor btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best I can tell, it only copies when you specify a format that's different from the Bitmap's format, or you use the ImageLockModeUserInputBuf flag.

You can test this by creating a Bitmap with a pointer to bits, such as [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536315(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536315%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Those bits are never copied into the Bitmap object. So you know that the bits are being copied if and only if you get a different pointer to the one you gave the constructor.

Another test you can do is lock for read-only access and try to write to the bits. The contents of the Bitmap will only change if you have direct access.

We have a lot of tests for LockBits in Wine, because it matters for compatibility with Windows programs that (ab)use this function: http://source.winehq.org/ident?i=GdipBitmapLockBits

Comment: "if and only if you get a different pointer to the one you gave the constructor" isn't true, it could map the same physical pages to a different region in the virtual address space... Though don't know why it would do this :). Will check the rest.